# Wix toolset изменить кодировку времени

Tags: winapi, wix

Как в wix toolset сменить вывод Time и Date? Мне нужно сделать вывод в таком виде - yyyymmdd_hhmmss. Или функция замены символов есть?

```
<SetProperty Before='AppSearch' Sequence='both' Id='HOSTNAME' Value="[ComputerName]_[Time]_[Date]">NOT HOSTNAME</SetProperty>
```

Comment: кто-нибудь есть?